# Which .NET Framework classes implement IDisposable

Tags: .net, idisposable

Seems like this has to be documented somewhere but I'm not finding is anywhere.  Perhaps my Google-fu is weakening.

Comment: I should clarify:  I'm looking for a non-coding answer.  I'm familiar with how to use reflection.  I'm looking for a link to an MDSN (or other) page that lists the classes that implement IDisposable.  If there's no such thing, I'll go the coding/reflection route.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you are attempting to go about this backwards. There are SOOOO many classes that implement IDisposable that just getting a list of them would serve no 'non-trivial' purpose. If you have a specific class that you wonder,"Does this implement IDisposable?" there are a variety of ways, from help and the MSDN library  to commanding the immediate window ? theClass is IDisposable (at runtime...) Are you just looking for a list to pin on the wall?

Comment: @goombaloon, go for the coding route, it's shorter and more importantly: more reliable than MSDN. Not to mention that the existence of such a link on MSDN wouldn't serve any practical purpose.

Comment: I'm working on an article and would like to be able to reference a list of .NET Framework class that implement IDisposable.  So, in a sense, yes, I'm kind of looking "for a list to pin on the wall".

Comment: @goombaloon, what do you mean by *.NET Framework class*? Until you clarify this notion I doubt you will find an easy answer.

Comment: @Darin - Yeah, I should clarify.  I'm interested in the System.* namespaces.

Comment: @goombaloon, in which assemblies? You realize that I can perfectly fine write a custom assembly containing a class in the System namespace. Would you be interested in this class as well? So once you answer this question you can perfectly fine adapt my answer and add an additional LINQ Where restriction with the namespace and you are good to go :-)

Comment: Sounds like the code route is the way to go.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You realize that this will depend on what you call *.NET Framework classes*. You probably might want to specify which assemblies you are looking for. Armed with this information you can load those assemblies and use reflection to list all public types that implement IDisposable in a given assembly. Let's take the System assembly as example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var types = Assembly
            .Load("System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => typeof(IDisposable).IsAssignableFrom(t))
            .OrderBy(t => t.Name);
        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(type);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this code not work for .NET Core assemblies? I am running against .NET Core and cant see any types returned.,

Comment: Not able to edit the ablove comment so adding a new one.

Below is code that worked for me for .Net Core

`
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(x => x.FullName.StartsWith("System"))
   .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
   .Where(t => typeof(IDisposable).IsAssignableFrom(t))
   .Select(t => new { Name = t.Name, Namespace = t.Namespace, Assembly = t.GetTypeInfo().Assembly });
  foreach (var type in types)
  {
   Console.WriteLine(type);
  }
`

Answer (score 6):

Using the code proposed by Darin Dimitrov, here is the list of framework Classes that implement IDisposable in a simple C# console application:

> Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider
>   Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeEventLogReadHandle
>   Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeEventLogWriteHandle
>   Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileMappingHandle
>   Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileMapViewHandle
>   Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeLibraryHandle
>   Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeLocalMemHandle
>   Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeProcessHandle
>   Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeThreadHandle
>   Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeTimerHandle
>   Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeUserTokenHandle
>   Microsoft.Win32.WinInetCache+ReadStream
>   Microsoft.Win32.WinInetCache+WriteStream
>   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider
>   System.CodeDom.Compiler.IndentedTextWriter
>   System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection1
>   System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList1+Enumerator
>   System.Collections.Generic.Queue1+Enumerator
>   System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary2+Enumerator
>   System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary2+KeyCollection+Enumerator
>   System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary2+ValueCollection+Enumerator
>   System.Collections.Generic.SortedList2+Enumerator
>   System.Collections.Generic.SortedList2+SortedListKeyEnumerator
>   System.Collections.Generic.SortedList2+SortedListValueEnumerator
>   System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet1+d__12
>   System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet1+Enumerator
>   System.Collections.Generic.Stack1+Enumerator
>   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection1+SimpleMonitor
>   System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker System.ComponentModel.Component
>   System.ComponentModel.Container
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerTransaction
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesigner
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.IRootDesigner
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.ITreeDesigner
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.SerializationStore
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.ServiceContainer
>   System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList
>   System.ComponentModel.IComponent System.ComponentModel.IContainer
>   System.ComponentModel.INestedContainer System.ComponentModel.License
>   System.ComponentModel.LicFileLicenseProvider+LicFileLicense
>   System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent
>   System.ComponentModel.NestedContainer
>   System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore+QuotaEnforcedStream
>   System.Diagnostics.AsyncStreamReader
>   System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener
>   System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener
>   System.Diagnostics.DelimitedListTraceListener
>   System.Diagnostics.EventLog System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry
>   System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal
>   System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener
>   System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter System.Diagnostics.Process
>   System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread
>   System.Diagnostics.ProcessWaitHandle
>   System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener
>   System.Diagnostics.TraceListener
>   System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener
>   System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream System.IO.Compression.GZipStream
>   System.IO.FileSystemWatcher System.IO.Ports.SerialPort
>   System.IO.Ports.SerialStream System.Media.SoundPlayer
>   System.Net.AsyncRequestContext System.Net.Base64Stream
>   System.Net.BaseWebProxyFinder System.Net.BufferedReadStream
>   System.Net.Cache.BaseWrapperStream System.Net.Cache.CombinedReadStream
>   System.Net.Cache.ForwardingReadStream
>   System.Net.Cache.MetadataUpdateStream System.Net.Cache.RangeStream
>   System.Net.Cache.SingleItemRequestCache+ReadOnlyStream
>   System.Net.Cache.SingleItemRequestCache+WriteOnlyStream
>   System.Net.ClosableStream System.Net.CommandStream
>   System.Net.Connection System.Net.ConnectStream
>   System.Net.DeflateWrapperStream System.Net.DelegatedStream
>   System.Net.DirectProxy System.Net.FileWebResponse
>   System.Net.FileWebStream System.Net.FtpControlStream
>   System.Net.FtpDataStream System.Net.FtpWebResponse
>   System.Net.FtpWebResponse+EmptyStream System.Net.GZipWrapperStream
>   System.Net.HttpListener System.Net.HttpListenerResponse
>   System.Net.HttpRequestQueueV2Handle System.Net.HttpRequestStream
>   System.Net.HttpResponseStream System.Net.HttpServerSessionHandle
>   System.Net.HttpWebResponse System.Net.HybridWebProxyFinder
>   System.Net.IWebProxyFinder System.Net.ListenerPrefixEnumerator
>   System.Net.Mail.AlternateView System.Net.Mail.AlternateViewCollection
>   System.Net.Mail.Attachment System.Net.Mail.AttachmentBase
>   System.Net.Mail.AttachmentCollection System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource
>   System.Net.Mail.LinkedResourceCollection System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient System.Net.Mail.SmtpPooledStream
>   System.Net.Mime.MimePart System.Net.Mime.QEncodedStream
>   System.Net.Mime.QuotedPrintableStream System.Net.Mime.SevenBitStream
>   System.Net.NetWebProxyFinder System.Net.NetworkAddressChangePolled
>   System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
>   System.Net.NetworkInformation.SafeCancelMibChangeNotify
>   System.Net.NetworkInformation.SafeFreeMibTable System.Net.PooledStream
>   System.Net.ProxyChain System.Net.ProxyChain+ProxyEnumerator
>   System.Net.ProxyScriptChain System.Net.RequestContextBase
>   System.Net.SafeCloseHandle System.Net.SafeCloseIcmpHandle
>   System.Net.SafeCloseSocket
>   System.Net.SafeCloseSocket+InnerSafeCloseSocket
>   System.Net.SafeCloseSocketAndEvent System.Net.SafeCredentialReference
>   System.Net.SafeDeleteContext System.Net.SafeDeleteContext_SCHANNEL
>   System.Net.SafeDeleteContext_SECUR32
>   System.Net.SafeDeleteContext_SECURITY System.Net.SafeFreeAddrInfo
>   System.Net.SafeFreeCertChain System.Net.SafeFreeCertContext
>   System.Net.SafeFreeContextBuffer
>   System.Net.SafeFreeContextBuffer_SCHANNEL
>   System.Net.SafeFreeContextBuffer_SECUR32
>   System.Net.SafeFreeContextBuffer_SECURITY
>   System.Net.SafeFreeContextBufferChannelBinding
>   System.Net.SafeFreeContextBufferChannelBinding_SCHANNEL
>   System.Net.SafeFreeContextBufferChannelBinding_SECUR32
>   System.Net.SafeFreeContextBufferChannelBinding_SECURITY
>   System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SCHANNEL
>   System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECUR32
>   System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY System.Net.SafeFreeCredentials
>   System.Net.SafeGlobalFree System.Net.SafeInternetHandle
>   System.Net.SafeLoadLibrary System.Net.SafeLocalFree
>   System.Net.SafeLocalFreeChannelBinding System.Net.SafeNativeOverlapped
>   System.Net.SafeOverlappedFree System.Net.SafeRegistryHandle
>   System.Net.SafeUnlockUrlCacheEntryFile
>   System.Net.Security.AuthenticatedStream
>   System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream System.Net.Security.SslStream
>   System.Net.Semaphore System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs
>   System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient
>   System.Net.StaticProxy System.Net.SyncMemoryStream
>   System.Net.SyncRequestContext System.Net.TimerThread+InfiniteTimer
>   System.Net.TimerThread+Timer System.Net.TimerThread+TimerNode
>   System.Net.TlsStream System.Net.WebClient
>   System.Net.WebClient+WebClientWriteStream System.Net.WebResponse
>   System.Net.WinHttpWebProxyFinder
>   System.Security.Authentication.ExtendedProtection.ChannelBinding
>   System.Security.Cryptography.SafeCertChainHandle
>   System.Security.Cryptography.SafeCertContextHandle
>   System.Security.Cryptography.SafeCertStoreHandle
>   System.Security.Cryptography.SafeCryptMsgHandle
>   System.Security.Cryptography.SafeCryptProvHandle
>   System.Security.Cryptography.SafeLibraryHandle
>   System.Security.Cryptography.SafeLocalAllocHandle
>   System.Threading.Barrier System.Threading.Semaphore
>   System.Timers.Timer

And this is the list for **System.Windows.Forms**:

> System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.BLOB
>   System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Manifest.AssemblyReferenceDependentAssemblyEntry
>   System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Manifest.DirectoryEntry
>   System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Manifest.FileEntry
>   System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Manifest.HashElementEntry
>   System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Manifest.MetadataSectionEntry
>   System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Manifest.MuiResourceMapEntry
>   System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Manifest.MuiResourceTypeIdIntEntry
>   System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Manifest.MuiResourceTypeIdStringEntry
>   System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Manifest.RegistryKeyEntry
>   System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Store+ApplicationPathLock
>   System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Store+AssemblyPathLock
>   System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Store+IPathLock
>   System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreTransaction
>   System.Resources.ResXResourceReader System.Resources.ResXResourceSet
>   System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter
>   System.Security.Policy.TrustManagerMoreInformation
>   System.Security.Policy.TrustManagerPromptUI
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application+MarshalingControl
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application+ModalApplicationContext
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application+ParkingWindow
>   System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext
>   System.Windows.Forms.ArrangedElement System.Windows.Forms.AxHost
>   System.Windows.Forms.AxHost+OleInterfaces
>   System.Windows.Forms.BindingNavigator
>   System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource System.Windows.Forms.Button
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase System.Windows.Forms.CachedItemHdcInfo
>   System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
>   System.Windows.Forms.ColorDialog System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader
>   System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog
>   System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu
>   System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip System.Windows.Forms.Control
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control+ActiveXImpl+AdviseHelper+ComConnectionPoint
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control+ActiveXImpl+AdviseHelper+ComConnectionPointContainer
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control+ActiveXImpl+AdviseHelper+SafeIUnknown
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control+FontHandleWrapper
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control+MetafileDCWrapper
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control+MultithreadSafeCallScope
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control+PrintPaintEventArgs
>   System.Windows.Forms.Cursor System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridBoolColumn
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridColumnStyle
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridTableStyle
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridTextBox
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridTextBoxColumn
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewBand
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonCell
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonColumn
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxCell
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxCell
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewHeaderCell
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewImageCell
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewImageColumn
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewLinkCell
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewLinkColumn
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowHeaderCell
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTopLeftHeaderCell
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataStreamFromComStream
>   System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
>   System.Windows.Forms.Design.ComponentEditorForm
>   System.Windows.Forms.Design.ComponentEditorForm+PageSelector
>   System.Windows.Forms.Design.ComponentEditorPage
>   System.Windows.Forms.DomainUpDown System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider
>   System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel
>   System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
>   System.Windows.Forms.FontDialog System.Windows.Forms.Form
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form+SecurityToolTip
>   System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox System.Windows.Forms.HelpProvider
>   System.Windows.Forms.HScrollBar
>   System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument+HtmlDocumentShim
>   System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement+HtmlElementShim
>   System.Windows.Forms.HtmlHistory System.Windows.Forms.HtmlShim
>   System.Windows.Forms.HtmlShimManager
>   System.Windows.Forms.HtmlWindow+HtmlWindowShim
>   System.Windows.Forms.IBindableComponent System.Windows.Forms.ImageList
>   System.Windows.Forms.ImageList+NativeImageList
>   System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer
>   System.Windows.Forms.Internal.DeviceContext
>   System.Windows.Forms.Internal.WindowsBrush
>   System.Windows.Forms.Internal.WindowsFont
>   System.Windows.Forms.Internal.WindowsGraphics
>   System.Windows.Forms.Internal.WindowsPen
>   System.Windows.Forms.Internal.WindowsRegion
>   System.Windows.Forms.Internal.WindowsSolidBrush
>   System.Windows.Forms.Label
>   System.Windows.Forms.Layout.IArrangedElement
>   System.Windows.Forms.Layout.LayoutTransaction
>   System.Windows.Forms.Layout.NullLayoutTransaction
>   System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
>   System.Windows.Forms.ListControl System.Windows.Forms.ListView
>   System.Windows.Forms.MainMenu System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
>   System.Windows.Forms.MdiClient System.Windows.Forms.MdiControlStrip
>   System.Windows.Forms.MdiControlStrip+ControlBoxMenuItem
>   System.Windows.Forms.MdiControlStrip+SystemMenuItem
>   System.Windows.Forms.MdiWindowDialog
>   System.Windows.Forms.MdiWindowListStrip System.Windows.Forms.Menu
>   System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip
>   System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar
>   System.Windows.Forms.MouseHoverTimer System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
>   System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
>   System.Windows.Forms.PageSetupDialog
>   System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs System.Windows.Forms.Panel
>   System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
>   System.Windows.Forms.PrintControllerWithStatusDialog+StatusDialog
>   System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog
>   System.Windows.Forms.PrintPreviewControl
>   System.Windows.Forms.PrintPreviewDialog
>   System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid
>   System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid+SnappableControl
>   System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.DocComment
>   System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.DropDownButton
>   System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.GridErrorDlg
>   System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.GridToolTip
>   System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.HotCommands
>   System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.PropertyGridView
>   System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.PropertyGridView+DropDownHolder
>   System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.PropertyGridView+GridViewEdit
>   System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.PropertyGridView+GridViewListBox
>   System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
>   System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBar
>   System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys+SKWindow
>   System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer System.Windows.Forms.Splitter
>   System.Windows.Forms.SplitterPanel System.Windows.Forms.StatusBar
>   System.Windows.Forms.StatusBarPanel System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip
>   System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip+RightToLeftLayoutGrip
>   System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
>   System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs
>   System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
>   System.Windows.Forms.TextBox System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase
>   System.Windows.Forms.ThreadExceptionDialog System.Windows.Forms.Timer
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolBar System.Windows.Forms.ToolBarButton
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripComboBox
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripComboBox+ToolStripComboBoxControl
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripContainer
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripContentPanel
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripControlHost
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownButton
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownItem
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownMenu
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripGrip System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripLabel
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripOverflow
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripOverflowButton
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripPanel
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripPanel+FeedbackRectangle
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripPanel+FeedbackRectangle+FeedbackDropDown
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripPanelCell
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripPanelRow
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProgressBar
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripScrollButton
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripScrollButton+StickyLabel
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSplitButton
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSplitButton+ToolStripSplitButtonButton
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripTextBox
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripTextBox+ToolStripTextBoxControl
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip+ToolTipTimer
>   System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
>   System.Windows.Forms.UpDownBase
>   System.Windows.Forms.UpDownBase+UpDownButtons
>   System.Windows.Forms.UpDownBase+UpDownEdit
>   System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
>   System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleRenderer+ThemeHandle
>   System.Windows.Forms.VScrollBar System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
>   System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser+WebBrowserSite
>   System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserBase
>   System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserSiteBase
>   System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext
>   System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsUtils+DCMapping
>   System.Windows.Forms.WindowsGraphicsWrapper

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want a list of all classes the implement `IDisposable`? It seems the more relevant question is "How can I tell if a class implements `IDisposable`?" If you need documentation, MSDN will tell you for a given class which interfaces it implements. If you need to know at compile-time, the compiler will yell at you if you try to wrap an object that isn't an instance of a class that implements `IDisposable` in a `using` block. If you need to know at runtime, you can use `var disposable = obj as IDisposable` and check if `disposable` is `null` or not.

If you have a specific assembly that you want to know about, you can rip through its types using reflection and test if those types implement `IDisposable` or not (use

```
typeof(IDisposable).IsAssignableFrom(type)
```

where `type` is an instance of `Type` that you've loaded from some `Assembly`.

Comment: Sometimes you want a list of classes that implement IDisposable! For instance I was reviewing code and reading through the list I remembered of classes I used, that needed to dispose where I forgot to call Dispose(). Of course you can check each class, but I found the list and Dimitrovs code snipped practical....