# Defensive Database Programming - should I be using a Singleton pattern

Tags: c#

Is the following defensive programming?

What I mean is that if it loses the connection, or some problem occurs during run-time and then the user runsit again will the .NET framework have tidied up any open connections and objects that were created when it first ran?

I've heard mention of a "Singleton pattern" - is this something I should use in the static method CreateConnection?

```
class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
     DataTable CasTable = fillSampleDataTable("SELECT top 100 * FROM x");
     //do other stuff
  }


  static SqlConnection CreateConnection() {
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XXX"].ConnectionString);
     return conn;
  }
  static SqlDataAdapter CreateAdapter(string myCommand) {
    SqlDataAdapter myAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand, CreateConnection());
    return myAdapt;
  }
  static DataTable fillSampleDataTable(string myCommand) {
      using (var adapt = CreateAdapter(myCommand)) {                   
            DataSet mySet = new DataSet();
            adapt.Fill(mySet, "SampleData");
            return mySet.Tables["SampleData"];
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you using the ADO.NET connection pool, a.k.a disposing the connections as soon as you have finished using them => wrap all IDisposable resources in `using` statements:

```
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        DataTable CasTable = fillSampleDataTable("SELECT top 100 * FROM x");
        //do other stuff
    }

    static DataTable fillSampleDataTable(string myCommand) 
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XXX"].ConnectionString;
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        using (var adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, conn)) 
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = myCommand;
            DataSet mySet = new DataSet();
            adapt.Fill(mySet, "SampleData");
            return mySet.Tables["SampleData"];
        }
    }
}
```

But normally DataSets and DataTables are artifacts of the past. Today you are better off using strongly typed models.

So define a model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then write a method that will return a list of those models:

```
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        var models = SelectTop100Models("SELECT top 100 * FROM x");
        //do other stuff
    }

    static IEnumerable<MyModel> SelectTop100Models() 
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XXX"].ConnectionString;
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT top 100 * FROM x";
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    yield return new MyModel
                    {
                        Id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ID")),
                        Name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Name")),
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you might consider using an ORM framework such as the [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) as it will simplify you querying the relational database and working directly with your strongly typed models using LINQ queries.

Comment: wonderful + food for thought + "artifacts of the past." = cool answer

Comment: one question darin - in the correction of my code why do you use `var` withing each of the `using` statements rather than the specific types?

Comment: also - if I'm playing with a biggish set of data (50,000 records that are 20 fields wide is the second method still the way forward?)

Comment: Yes, the second method is the way to go. It is even more true for bigger resultsets because you will not be loading all the records in memory at once. You could process the `IEnumerable<T>` as you wish whereas with the DataSet you have no choice - all the records are loaded. If you have really large resultsets with millions of records a DataSet would be a complete overkill.

Comment: Thanks; two more tiny questions before you go - is code such as this : `using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())` just applicable to ADO database programming or can this `using` structure be used in other circumstances e.g when I'm programming with Excel interops? (+ why do you use `var` instead of explicitly writing the type?

Comment: Everytime a type implements `IDisposable` you should wrap it in a `using` structure to ensure proper disposal. It is not only related to ADO.NET.

Comment: OK - I'll do a bit of searching around to find the types which implement that interface

Comment: looks like you comments in [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034728/which-net-framework-classes-implement-idisposable) are a good place for me to start!

Comment: ok straight away VS is giving me an error for `using (var excelApp = new Excel.Application());` so there's my answer

Comment: how come in the entity code there is no parameter in `static IEnumerable<MyModel> SelectTop100Models()` ...I'll attempt to edit; if you've got time please correct my mistakes as I'd like to start experimenting with this code as it looks like fun

Comment: ....looks like with your suggestion every time it iterates it will be making a connection with the database. With a good old honest datatable it gets the data in one round trip + the datatable inherits this enumeration already so loops are fine. Only drawback is that dt isn't so type safe. Maybe swings and roundabouts?

Comment: @whytheq, what do you mean by *everytime it iterates it will make a connection to the database*?

Comment: I think I'll start a new question on this - will pop a link to it here

Comment: Darin ....I'm never very good at explaining myself. But the following snippet seemed to return a strange set of data:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437657/if-using-ienumerator-on-strongly-typed-class-does-it-make-many-trips-to-the-serv