# If using IEnumerator on strongly-typed class does it make many trips to the server

Tags: c#

This is a very simple (and pointless) example of a var type that has enumerator properties. The point of the snippet is to experiment with a collection using a strongly-typed class that implements the `IEnumerator` interface.

```
public class num { public int value { get; set; } }

class Program {

    private int[] data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Program p = new Program();
        var numbers = selectNumbers(p.data);


        foreach(num x in numbers) {
            Console.WriteLine("Found {0}", x.value.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit");
        Console.Read();
    }

    static IEnumerable<num> selectNumbers(int[] x) {
        //in production app the following would use a reader to get data from database
        for(int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++) {
            yield return new num { value = x[i] };
            Console.WriteLine("Found {0}", x[i].ToString()); // <<<(1)
        }
    }
}
```

The results returned to the console are slightly strange. The results seem to suggest that every time an iteration of the `foreach` loop executes line (1) also executes.

Does this mean that if I implemented this structure to database setting application, where `selectNumbers` involved getting in touch with our database, would it then be making a connection every time IEnumerator is used? e.g. every time it then uses a `foreach` loop on the strongly-typed `num` would it be getting in touch with our database? The results of this example seem to suggest that it would.

Comment: [`yield return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9k7k7cf0.aspx) will return control back to the caller until it is called again or it runs out of elements to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how [`yield return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9k7k7cf0.aspx) works. The compiler constructs a state machine to implement the `IEnumerable<T>` interface. The example I have shown you with database access was in [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12446960/29407). In this example the state machine will continue where it previously left on the previous iteration which is inside the `while` loop and not at the beginning of the method:

```
static IEnumerable<MyModel> SelectTop100Models() 
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XXX"].ConnectionString;
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT top 100 * FROM x";
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // EXECUTION WILL CONTINUE FROM HERE AND NOT AT THE BEGINNING
                // OF THE METHOD
                yield return new MyModel
                {
                    Id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ID")),
                    Name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Name")),
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So you shouldn't be worried at all about making multiple connections to the database. This code is very optimized.

Comment: ahh - so we could theoretically move `yield return` to a different position in the `SelectTop100Models` method and that would move the starting point for the foreach iterations?